# IE adds extra top-margin to every li-element

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am currently doing IE-hacks on a website I'm working on:
http://www.timkjaerlange.com/wip/co2penhagen/

I got a problem with this unordered list. IE seems to add extra top-margin for every li-element, making my navigation look like a flight of stairs: 
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/228089/ie-prob.jpg

I'm using conditional comments to target IE. I tried:

```
ul#mainnav li { top-margin: 0;}
```

But that doesn't do anything. I wish there was a Firebug-style plugin for IE, that would make it easier to sort out problems like these.

Any ideas regarding what could be causing this problem?

Comment: God bless the star selector. I just added `li{*margin-top:-4px;}` and it got fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the behavior your looking for try "display: inline" instead of the "float: left".  Add both:

> ul#mainnav { display: inline }
>
> ul#mainnav li { display: inline }

A great resource for info on customizing lists can be found on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/).

Answer (score 2):

top-margin isn't a CSS attribute.  You're looking for margin-top

Change:

```
ul#mainnav li { top-margin: 0;}
```

To:

```
ul#mainnav li { margin-top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

err..sorry if this is a silly question, but shouldn't that be margin-top?

Maybe you should consider customizing a well-designed [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (or this [one](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)) file for your use?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. However margin-top doesn't solve the problem

I use Eric Meyer's reset.css, it's bundled with 960gs that I use for prototyping the design.